# DEoptim: how to optimize more than one parameter?

Tags: r, parameters, deoptimization

I want to fit a curve,the model is as the following picture.

[image]

In this model, there are four parameters(alpha,beta,gamma and Rd)to optimize,now the data of I and P(I) is already,and the function `DEoptim()` from `DEoptim` package in `R` is used,this is my code.

```
library(DEoptim)
I <-c(1.200,49.600,99.200,148.500,199.300,399.375,598.200,799.500,1099.600,1398.100,1698.600,1844.333)
pn <-c(-0.0495485,0.4166522,0.8954644,1.4592700,1.9931400,2.9114072,3.0808183,3.2427603,3.3916783,3.6078660,4.1020850,4.0947913)

fn.piao <- function(alpha,beta,gamma,Rd){
   pn <- (alpha-alpha*beta*par)/(1+gamma*par)-Rd      
}

lower <- c(0,0,0,0)
upper <- c(1,1,1,100)
DE.control <- list(itermax=500,NP=100)

DE.piao <- DEoptim(lower,upper,fn=fn.piao,par=par,control=DE.control)
```

but R shows error as follows

> Error in DEoptim(lower, upper, fn = fn.piao, par = par, control =
>   DE.control) : object is not a matrix

In the paper (K.M. Mullen2011), it says *i*th element of **lower** and **upper** applies to the *i*th parameter. so i set the vector **lower**and **upper** to represent alpha, beta, gamma and Rd.i want to ask where is my fault and how to adjust?